# JQuery - How to transfer data from show.bs.modal keyup function

Tags: jquery

Using Laravel-5.8 application and I JQuery modal and some other functions. I have this code:

```html
@foreach($goals as $key => $goal)
<tr>
  <td class="myRatingLimit">
    {{ $goal->goaltype->ratingLimit ? $goal->goaltype->ratingLimit->max_rating : '' }}
  </td>
  <td class="myWeightedScore">
    {{$goal->weighted_score ?? '' }}
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" data-target="#modal_add_comment" data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{ $goal->id }}" data-original-title="Comment">
      <i class="fas text-white">Add Comment</i>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

I have this JQuery as shown below:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.modal_add_comment').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
      var $this = $(e.relatedTarget);
      var data_id = $this.data('id');
      var modal = $this;

      var parentTr = $this.closest('tr');
      var myRatingLimit = parentTr.find('.myRatingLimit').text();
      var myWeightedScore = parentTr.find('.myWeightedScore').text();

      // directly use .val() instead of .attr()
      var newRating = modal.find('.InputRatingLimit').val(myRatingLimit);
      var newScore = modal.find('.InputWeightedScore').val(myWeightedScore);

      var newScore1 = $(".InputWeightedScore").val();
      var newRating1 = $(".InputRatingLimit").val();

    });

    $(".myRating").on('keyup blur', function(e) {
      var main = myWeightedScore;
      var perc = myRatingLimit;
      main = main ? parseInt(main) : 0;
      perc = perc ? parseInt(perc) : 0;
      let sumWeightBalance = parseInt(main);
      let sumPercBalance = parseInt(perc);
      var percVal = (sumPercBalance / 100).toFixed(2);
      var mult = main * percVal;
      var percResult = main + mult;
      let sumValue = parseInt($(".myRating").val());
      console.log(sumValue);
      if (sumValue > percResult) {
        Swal('Oops...', 'Self Rating is greater than Rating Limit!', 'error')
        $(".myRating").val('');
        return false;
      }
    });

  }); <
/script>

The modal form looks like this:
```

```html
<div id="modal_add_comment_{{ $goal->id }}" class="modal fade modal_add_comment" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form action="{{route('appraisal.appraisal_year_end_setups.employee_year_end_comment',['id'=>$goal->id])}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="review_comment-form">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="modal-header">
          Self-Review Comment
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label"> Rating:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
            <input type="hidden" name="InputRatingLimit" class="InputRatingLimit">
            <input type="hidden" name="InputWeightedScore" class="InputWeightedScore">
            <input type="text" name="employee_year_end_weighted_score" class="form-control myRating" placeholder="Enter Rating here e.g. 10" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" style="width: 100%;"
              maxlength="4" required/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default close-modal-create" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel
                    </button>
          <button type="submit" id="review_comment_btn-submit" class="btn btn-success btn-ok">Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to transfer the values of myRatingLimit and myWeightedScore in  show.bs.modal:

```
  var myRatingLimit = parentTr.find('.myRatingLimit').text();
  var myWeightedScore = parentTr.find('.myWeightedScore').text();
```

into:

$(".myRating").on('keyup blur', function(e) {

as

```
  var main = myWeightedScore;
  var perc = myRatingLimit;
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare the `var myRatingLimit, myWeightedScore;` outside `$('.modal_add_comment').on()` method if it doesn't impose any problem.

**Update**

You will get `NaN` error when parsing empty `$(".myRating")` value. Thus use an *empty check* and *NaN check* before parsing.

```
const myRating = $(".myRating").val();
let sumValue = myRating.length === 0 || isNaN(myRating) ? 0 : parseInt(myRating);
console.log(`sumValue is ${sumValue}`);
```

The whole code snippet is added below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // **Treat like global variable**
  var myRatingLimit, myWeightedScore;

  $('.modal_add_comment').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var $this = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var data_id = $this.data('id');
    var modal = $this;
    var parentTr = $this.closest('tr');
    
    // **Reuse the vars instead of re-declaring them**
    myRatingLimit = parentTr.find('.myRatingLimit').text();
    myWeightedScore = parentTr.find('.myWeightedScore').text();

    // directly use .val() instead of .attr()
    var newRating = modal.find('.InputRatingLimit').val(myRatingLimit);
    var newScore = modal.find('.InputWeightedScore').val(myWeightedScore);
    var newScore1 = $(".InputWeightedScore").val();
    var newRating1 = $(".InputRatingLimit").val();
  });

  $(".myRating").on('keyup blur', function(e) {
    var main = myWeightedScore;
    var perc = myRatingLimit;
    main = main ? parseInt(main) : 0;
    perc = perc ? parseInt(perc) : 0;
    let sumWeightBalance = parseInt(main);
    let sumPercBalance = parseInt(perc);
    var percVal = (sumPercBalance / 100).toFixed(2);
    var mult = main * percVal;
    var percResult = main + mult;

    // **You will get NaN error when parsing empty value**
    // **Thus use a empty check and NaN check before**
    const myRating = $(".myRating").val();
    let sumValue = myRating.length === 0 || isNaN(myRating) ? 0 : parseInt(myRating);
    console.log(`sumValue is ${sumValue}`);
    if (sumValue > percResult) {
      Swal('Oops...', 'Self Rating is greater than Rating Limit!', 'error')
      $(".myRating").val('');
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modal_add_comment_{{ $goal->id }}" class="modal fade modal_add_comment" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form action="{{route('appraisal.appraisal_year_end_setups.employee_year_end_comment',['id'=>$goal->id])}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="review_comment-form">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="modal-header">
          Self-Review Comment
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label"> Rating:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
            <input type="hidden" name="InputRatingLimit" class="InputRatingLimit">
            <input type="hidden" name="InputWeightedScore" class="InputWeightedScore">
            <input type="text" name="employee_year_end_weighted_score" class="form-control myRating" placeholder="Enter Rating here e.g. 10" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" style="width: 100%;"
              maxlength="4" required/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default close-modal-create" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel
                    </button>
          <button type="submit" id="review_comment_btn-submit" class="btn btn-success btn-ok">Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On keyup, it shows undefined for     var main = myWeightedScore;
    var perc = myRatingLimit;

Comment: Perhaps you didn't notice the changes I did, thus made the snippet shorter. Check the 2nd line in the snippet.

Comment: That's what I did:   var myRatingLimit, myWeightedScore;

Comment: And don't re-declare those vars again. Use
`myRatingLimit = parentTr.find('.myRatingLimit').text();
myWeightedScore = parentTr.find('.myWeightedScore').text();`

Comment: Thanks a lot. The only problem now is that console.log(sumValue); for let sumValue = parseInt($(".myRating").val()); displays NaN and this makes this validation not to work:              if (sumValue > percResult) {
              Swal('Oops...', 'Self Rating is greater than Rating Limit!', 'error')
              $(".myRating").val('');

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you! Please consider marking it as correct so it can help other people checking this question also! :)